# ASP.NET site redirecting one domain to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

How safe is using the asp.net Global.asax to redirect one domain to another?

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Trim().ToLower().Contains("mydomainb.net"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.myrealdomainSample.com");
    }        
}
```

Would the above code overload the site?

Comment: Why not do it in web.config with IIS' URLRewriter instead?

Comment: A site gets overloaded if it receives more requests than it can handle. Redirecting doesn't overload anything. It's all about how many requests are received. Which site are you worried about overloading?

Comment: Thank you Dai. and Thank you also Scott Hannen for your reply, I think I asked that wrong by mentioning overloading site, what I am trying learn is, if you experts, recommend using the Global.asax to redirect from one site to another or what would be the best coding in this case. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Redirect()` actually calls the `Response.End()` method which will directly abort the current thread.

if you are looking for a "safe" way to truncate an `HttpRequest`, meaning that it with truncate without having an exception thrown this could be accomplished by using the `HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()` (note that this will result in further code execution in the current request)

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about `Response.End()`'s horrible implementation. Who on earth thought that throwing `ThreadAbortException` _as part of normal program flow_ was a good idea?

Comment: Thank you Dai, this is a learning curve for me and trying my best to code clean, would you recommend using Global.asax for one site to another redirection? what would be the best implementation in my case, I am trying to make code as clean and better as possible to avoid future headaches.